# Is there a way to perform Clojure-oriented reflection?

Tags: clojure

If I have a function like

```
(defn ab_func [a b]
  (* a b))
```

how do I use reflection to determine that ab_func takes two arguments? clojure.reflect seems to front-end the Java reflection machinery... I'm looking for some level of reflection that doesn't require understanding the Java implementation of clojure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function vars have metadata associated that will allow you to determine the number of arguments that a function takes, e.g.:

```
(-> (meta #'ab_func) :arglists first count)
=> 2
```

Comment: This is the closest Clojure has to a general-purpose reflection mechanism, but note that it only applies to functions defined with `defn`. Since the metadata is attached to the var, it isn't available for anonymous functions created with `(fn)`.

Comment: That is really useful to know, thanks. Seems like a weird oversight.

Answer (score 2):

You can get access to the argument lists of the function by calling `(meta #'ab_func)`.

(Also, the name `ab-func` would be more in accordance with Clojure naming convenctions than `ab_func`.)

Comment: Thanks for the note about naming conventions... am just learning clojure.